# Comparing two columns of strings in excel, identify if A1,B1 contains the reverse anywhere (as Bx, Ax)

Tags: excel

Assume a simple excel sheet with the same 500 names, randomized into two columns.

I'm trying to identify columns where the values in A and B (let's say Bob Jones in A1 and Mary Smith in B1) also align with the SAME values in reverse (where Mary Smith also appears in A7, we find Bob Jones in B7).

For arguments sake, let's say it's a Secret Santa list, and we want to flag where people in Column A are not allowed to just have a "one way trade" someone from column B... does this make sense?

In a perfect world, this would be a conditional formatting pass... that highlights these "conflicts". At that point, I could manually adjust the few that got stuck, but doing this with two columns of 500 rows is very hard to do manually.

Comment: And your question is....?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: My question was "how do I identify these overlaps?" So far I've colored certain values (fill all cells with Bob Jones as red, and all cells of Mary Smith as green), and see if the red and green line up twice, but on a larger scale. I'm trying to leverage something more efficient than cell fills and my eyeballs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your names are in A1:B500, then in C1:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$A$1:$B$500,2,FALSE)=A1
```

and fill down

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much. It returns one of three values: True, False, or #N/A, but I can focus on the Trues and do what I need. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column C that is =concatenate(A,B) and add a column D that is concatenate(B,A).

Then use select C:D (select all the rows of column C and D).  Click on conditional formatting, New Rule..., Format only unique or duplicate values, and follow the rest of the prompt window.

This should leave you with cells in column c and d formatted the way you choose allowing you to easily see what rows have a one way trade.

Pro Tip:  If you set your conditionally formatting to create a background fill color, you can then sort based on cell color to bring those to the top or bottom of your list.

Comment: this would work for numbers, but not names... right? Bob Jones + Mary Clark = ?

Comment: Oops, I've been using python too much recently where you can "add" strings.  In excel you can use the concatenate function.  I've updated my answer to include that.